# Magento 2: How to change the icon in product description page?

Tags: magento-2.1, product-page

in product description page, after adding to chart page I have 2 icons, 1st for add to favorite and 2nd for share And I want to change this like this and want to change star rating color to pink. how can I do it? I want something like this

[image]

Someone said I need to change in `AddtoLinks.php`

```
if ($this->wishlistHelper->isAllow())
            {
                $html .= '
                <a href="#"
                    class="action towishlist '. $linkClass .'"
                    title="' . $this->wishlistLabel . '"
                    aria-label="' . $this->wishlistLabel . '"
                    data-post=\'' . /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->wishlistHelper->getAddParams($product) . '\'
                    data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                    role="button">
                        <span class="icon ib ib-hover ic ic-heart '. $iconClass .'"></span>
                        <span class="label">' . $this->wishlistLabel . '</span>
                </a>
                ';
            }
```

Comment: are you looking for Magento1 or Magento2?

Comment: magento 2 @DhirenVasoya its magento 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the wishlist, you have to override the following template by placing it under your theme folder

```
/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Wishlist/templates/catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml
```

before

```
<span class="label">' . $this->wishlistLabel . '</span>
```

add

```
<img src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/your_image_name'); ?>" />
```

or via css add a background image

```
.product-social-links .action.towishlist:before {
    background-image: url(your_image_path);
}
```

for the rating star you have to change the color attribute for the following element

```
.rating-summary .rating-result>span:before {
    color: your_color
}
```

Comment: Color changing worked for me . but for wishlist I am confuse how to insert new logo type thing.

Comment: Answer updated!

Comment: before

<span class="label">' . $this->wishlistLabel . '</span>   ?  it it belong to xml file ?

Comment: no it belogs to the template file

Comment: okay mean both lines to be pasted in  wishlist.phtml  ?

Comment: background-image: url("../web/images/logo.png");   I tried but not changing through css :(

Comment: done :)  My image changed doing this                                                                  span.icon.ib.ib-hover.ic.ic-heart.icon-color-productview {
    content: url('../images/logo.png') !important;
    width: 73px;
}